# How to sign and align an android application generated by Intel XDK?

Tags: intel-xdk

I want to use my custom keystore in this project because I intend to host the application in PlayStore and keep it updated. Without the keystore will be tricky.

*Details: In the settings cordova, I not marked the "Signed" box and I exported the app and tried signing it using javasign. At the command prompt went well but the app does not install on any of the devices I tested.*

Answer (score 1):

The APK created by the Intel XDK is created using standard Cordova CLI. So the techniques you would use to sign that APK are no different than what you would use with any other Cordova (or PhoneGap) app or an APK built using Eclipse or any other tools.

See these links for some useful information:

-- http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

-- https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/861/how-to-sign-and-align-your-android-app-apk